# Get XML declarations on its own lines

Tags: xml, xslt, xhtml

I have an XSLT file that starts out like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> 
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:processing-instruction name="xml-stylesheet">type="text/xsl" href="xhtml_transition.xslt"</xsl:processing-instruction>
<root>
  <child>
    ....
```

The result is all fine except for one small detail. In the output the first declarations is printed on a single line:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="xhtml_transition.xslt"?<root>
    <child>
        ....
```

I want this result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="xhtml_transition.xslt"?
  <root>
    <child>
      ....
```

How do I get my processing-instruction to print on its own line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
<xsl:template match="/" xml:space="preserve">
<xsl:processing-instruction name="xml-stylesheet">type="text/xsl" href="xhtml_transition.xslt"</xsl:processing-instruction>
<root>
```

or

```
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
<xsl:processing-instruction name="xml-stylesheet">type="text/xsl" href="xhtml_transition.xslt"</xsl:processing-instruction>
<root>
```

Comment: I generally try to avoid xml:space="preserve" in stylesheets as it can give you more whitespace in the output than you bargained for, and the people debugging your code in five years time won't spot the significance of the xml:space attribute.

Comment: @MichaelKay, agreed but I only put `xml:space` on one template and I posted an alternative way to do what the poster wanted so he has a chance to to try and test which approach does what he wanted.

Comment: I used the second alternative. Even though xsltproc actually gave me the correct output anyway.